# Entity Framework - Querying Inheritance

Tags: .net, entity-framework, inheritance, navigation-properties

I was tasked as a homework assignment to make a task tracker. I wanted to learn entity framework for this assignment, especially how to use the inheritance aspects. Projects, tasks and sub-tasks all have a lot of similar properties, so I thought I would use inheritance, but can't figure out how to query particular projects.

I drew this diagram in Visual Studio:

[image: Entity Diagram]

I then created the database from this model. How can I get an Employees Projects?

I've started with this:

```
ModelContainer m = new ModelContainer();
var employee = (from e in m.Employees 
               where e.UserName == username
               select e).First<Employee>();
```

But `((Employee)employee).Projects` is not available, but `((Employee)employee).Items` is. `((Employee)employee).Items.Projects` is also not available. How do I get an Employee's projects? Should I add a *Navigation Property* to Employees for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use the [Queryable.OfType(TResult) extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344857.aspx) in order to filter the entities of type Manager:

```
using (var model = new ModelContainer())
{
    Manager manager = (from m in model.Employees.OfType<Manager>()
                       where m.UserName == username
                       select m).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [Inheritance and Associations with Entity Framework Part 3](http://mosesofegypt.net/post/Inheritance-and-Associations-with-Entity-Framework-Part-3.aspx)
- [Lerman, Julia, Programming Entity Framework, O'Reilly 2010](http://books.google.com/books?id=rtdgHbMeTBMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=programming+entity+framework&hl=en&ei=9oT1TOaIFYiUOoXO5KQI&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)